# Trying to use .Find to search for an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm currently trying to use .Find to search for an array of items starting with "K". If there is a match then proceed to filter and delete the item. However, I'm not sure if .Find is able to incorporate the array into its condition. I've considered using For each and If, but the code would be considerably long. Anyone can help or give suggestion for a different method?

```
Dim ckFOH As Range
Dim Krange As Variant

Krange = Sheets("Master List").Range("G17:G" & Range("G17").End(xlDown).Row)

With Sheets("FOH")
    Set ckFOH = .Columns("Q").Find(What:=Krange, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not ckFOH Is Nothing Then
        .Rows("5").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="=K*"
        .Range("A6:K" & Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

`Find()` method of `Range` object accepts any data type for its "What" parameter, but if you provide a `Range` (as per your code) or even a 1D array, it's only its first element being actually searched for

moreover from your description I believe that you want to delete all sheet "FOH" rows that have any of actual "K" values found in "Master List" column Q

so you may want to use `AutoFilter()` and directly filter column Q on all those values providing an array as `Criteria1` parameter  and activating its `xlFilterValues` *Operator* option

as per following code (further explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim Krange As Variant

    With Sheets("Master List") 'reference wanted sheet
        Krange = Application.Transpose(.Range("G17", .Range("G17").End(xlDown)).Value) ' store referenced sheet column G values from row 17 down to last consecutive not empty cell - explicitly qualify ALL range references to referenced worksheet
    End With

    With Sheets("FOH") 'reference wanted sheet
        With .Range("Q5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp)) 'reference its column Q range from row 5 (header) to last not empty row
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Krange, Operator:=xlFilterValues ' filtere referenec range on all 'Krange' array values
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete ' if any filtered cells other then header, thene delete their entire rows
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: IMO, a brief explanation of the problem and your solution *before the code* is worth so much more than comments in code

Comment: Thanks @DisplayName but I'm unable to use .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp) to select my filter range as I have other data in the sheet. So i resorted to using .End(xlDown).Row and the problem with this is if K* items doesn't exist, the code ends up deleting random lines and rows.

Comment: @kchungg, what do you mean by _"if K* items doesn't exist"_? Are you referring to items in "Master List" or in "FOH" sheet? Please give more details

Comment: @DisplayName the initial plan is to use .find to determine whether sheet "FOH" contain _K*_ items from "Master List". If it doesn't then the code does not run. In sheet "FOH", below the _autofilter data_ contains other datas, thus i used `.End(xlDown).Row` to determine the last row for the autofilter. However when _K*_ does not exist, `.End(xlDown).Row` starts to select unnecessary data. I tried using `.Count > 1` but I'm still unable to solve my problem.